# Why are programs not written using physical addresses?

Tags: memory, operating-system, paging

I'm in the process of studying for my OS class' final exam, and I stumbled upon this question on one of my professor's slides. My guess is that it's really hard to do it and hence not very practical in terms of the amount of production you could get - you'd have to somehow keep track of what part of physical memory that is being used by every program, be careful not to write in areas that are mapped to various devices, etc.

Is that about right or am I missing something?

Comment: Lots of reasons. I'll give one from security: if an attacker knows where a library is loaded precisely, it can be easier for them to exploit your program. This leads to [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important reasons why we have virtual memory has to do on how executable code works. Considering the simplest example `a = 12345` here is how assembly would look (simplified for obvious reasons, everything is an int):

```
Memory Address:Content at address
00000000000004: 12345 (or binary: 11000000111001)
00000000000008: a (phisical location of a)
0000000000000C: copy from 00000000000004 to 00000000000008 instruction
```

The important part is `copy from 00000000000004 to 00000000000008 instruction`
what that does is just copy a bunch of memory from one location from another.

When you try to execute this program you **must** have `a` and `12345` at those locations otherwise it will not work. If the memory would be physical directly you program would only work if it is always placed in the same memory location.
This is solved by [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) so that virtually everything is in the same place, leaving the placement in the physical memory to the operating system (using [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)). Without that you would have to change all instructions in the code whenever the program runs to the physical location and that would only make programs bigger and slower.

Virtual memory solves multiple problems. First, it allows for multiple programs to run on the same machine. Second, it allows the OS to do extra security by [randomizing the position of each page in the ram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). Also you can theoretically allocate more memory than you physical memory because the OS can move memory from RAM to HDD and back whenever the program needs it ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault)).

Comment: Thanks for the detail in your answer. So besides the security issue, writing your programs using physical addresses makes them inflexible in the sense that every time you change to another physical location, you'd have to modify the addresses of all of your instructions (or the instructions themselves?) to match what's on that new machine. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you have to modify in all places where addresses are referenced in you program. References can be anywhere; in instructions (move from LocA to LocB, or jump to LocD, etc) and in data also (can't think of an example). Anyway, it is up to the compiler to do whatever it wants with the code soup and you could end up with literately billions of address references anywhere.

Comment: There has been a system whose name I unfortunately don't remember who circumvented this problem without virtual memory by modifying all physical address of a program **at runtime** and fitting it into the address space. This comes along with a significant performance impact, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for using logical address translation. The big one is that it make implementing security simpler by separating each process.

It also allows remapping of memory and memory sharing. Multiple processes can map the same physical page at different logical addresses.

It is a prerequisite for virtual memory (a concept distinct, but related to logical memory translation).

It allows all processes (and east instance of the same application) to have the same memory layout.

It largely eliminates the need for the kernel to allocate contiguous blocks (page frames) of memory for processes. A continuous logical address space can be created from discontiguous page frames.